# How do I share an image from react native to another app?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to share an image loaded in a component to another app (such as Whatsapp).

If I have the following:

```
...
<Image
    source={{ uri: image.uri }} // 'https://my-s3-bucket/...' NOT 'file://...'
    onLongPress={() => shareImage(image.uri)}
/>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by downloading the image locally first, sharing it with Expo Sharing, and then deleting it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) by install :

```
yarn add react-native-share
```

or if you use npm :

```
npm install react-native-share --save
```

This module can help you share url and file

Comment: I dont have access to iOS or Android directory, Im using expo, so I cant set this up unfortunately and I dont want to eject. Is there another way?